# Sql query is executing endlessly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run a simple sql query on Sql Server, but it does not stop to execute.

```
  UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = Table_B.[Miktar]
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT [Miktar], [UrunID] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
                GROUP BY [UrunID], [Miktar] ) AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID]
```

Can there be loop? Please help
Here is a little part of first table

```
Depo    SatisID SatisSira   UrunID    Satici    KdvKod  KDVYuzde    Miktar
AZ01    20001   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20002   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   1           3876390   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   2           3793202   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   3           4046508   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   4           3843387   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   5           3850608   999       AZ       18.00      1
```

And the second

```
BaslikID    Sira    UrunID   Miktar Fiyat   Depo
20001       1       3792703  1      1       AZ01  
20002       1       4067131  1      1       AZ01  
20003       1       3251881  1      1       AZ01  
20003       2       3251883  1      1       AZ01  
20003       3       3788887  1      1       AZ01  
20003       4       3788890  1      1       AZ01  
20004       1       3761260  2      1       AZ01
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when the subquery returns two records with the same UrunID value, but different Miktar value. Which of the two will the record in Table_A get?

Comment: There really isn't such things as loops in update, but you might have blocking, or if your tables are big, this isn't a simple query anymore.

Comment: There is no loop; you must have a large number of rows being updated and your SQL Server isn't powerful enough to execute the transaction or is being otherwise bogged down by other transactions.

Comment: execute sp_who2 and check if there is any other session blocking your session

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables (I'm looking at the UrunID columns)

Comment: How many rows are returned by the query:`SELECT [Miktar], [UrunID] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay] GROUP BY [UrunID], [Miktar]`  Also, are there indexes on Table_A for the values `Miktar` and `UrunID`? Are these part of a clustered index? How many rows are in Table_A?

Comment: I ve added a part of tables to show how many rows are there and relations. Well, actually the real task was to take Sum of Miktar for each UrunID from the first table and spread it in the second for each UrunID. Now I see that the amount of records by UrunID may not match. So endless execution is not the only problem.

Comment: And talking about blocking I ve already checked by running SP_WHO2 ACTIVE. There is no BlkBy

Answer (score 0):

There can be a conflict as to which value to update `Table_A` with: if the subquery returns more than one record for the same `UrunID`, then it will be ambiguous which of the `Miktar` values should be used for updating the `Table_A` record.

So make sure the subquery only returns one record per `UrunID`:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = Table_B.[Miktar]
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT   [UrunID], Min([Miktar]) as Miktar 
                    FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
                GROUP BY [UrunID]
               ) AS Table_B
            ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID]
```

Comment: This won't necessarily speed anything up - could be quite the opposite actually.

Comment: Well, actually each UrunID does contain several records, and the real task is to take the sum of Miktar for each UrunID and spread in the second table for each UrunID. I tried SUM(A.Miktar)/COUNT(B.Miktar), but it executes endlessly.

Comment: Do you have an index on `UrunID`? Do you mean `Table_A` with *the second table*?

Comment: Yes, take from table A (satisDetay) and update DepoSevkDetay. About indexes, I have found this on the second table <br> <pre>Depo  dbo.dt_Depo(char(6)) 6 No No
SatisID  int 4 No No
SatisSira  int 4 No No
UrunID  int 4 No No
</pre>

Comment: Please put this information in your question, where it will be more readable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, `UPDATE` by using `JOIN` is slower than correlated query. Here I assume the `Miktar` is unique per each `UrunID`

```
 UPDATE Table_A as A
 SET [Miktar] = 
(SELECT [Miktar] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay] as B where B.[UrunID] = A.[UrunID])
```

And I think it will fail if there are 1-many relationship existing between `UrunID` and `Miktar`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you have proper indexes in place for the columns involved in `JOIN` condition. don't see the need of `group by` in subquery at all. You can change your query to be like below. just posting the query isn't enough. consider posting the query execution plan as well.

```
  UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = Table_B.[Miktar]
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay] AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID];
```